# Spring data mongo db find in map of values

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have the following DB structure:

```
{  id : "1233454",
   name : "abc",
   elements : [ 
        { "1" : { id : "123", referenceId : "567" } },
        { "2" : { id : "345" } },
   ],
},
{  id : "56789",
   name : "def",
   elements : [ 
        { "3" : { id : "123", referenceId : "789" } },
        { "4" : { id : "345" } },
   ],
},
{  id : "98765",
   name : "def",
   elements : [ 
        { "3" : { id : "123", referenceId : "789" } },
        { "4" : { id : "345" } },
   ],
}
```

and I need to retrieve document id where referenceId is equals to the parameter passed to the method.
For example: If method receives "789" it should return "56789" and "98765".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any particular rule/schema for the keys in your `elements` array elements? Can it be any string?

Comment: id field is the key of the document. "1233454", "56789" and "98765" are document keys.

Comment: you seem to get my question wrong, see my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to have unknown keys if you want to query efficiently, see for example [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/MrANONUL2Fg). If your keys in the `elements` (e.g. `"1"`) follow a certain structure or are limited, you could use a simple `$or` in the query to check all options such as `"elements.1.referenceId"` - see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#d0e1989) how to do this.